# Grouping duplicates till a specific count

Tags: java, grouping

I have a number of xml's that come in haphazardly that contain a Ocount, and Lnumber, as well as other data. I have created a class to get that data.

My problem is that how can I group xml's that have the same **Lnumber(string), until it reaches the Ocount(int).** (the xmls that have the same lnumber has the same Ocount). And eventually send out a email telling with xmls has been processed.

```
String readLine = FileHandler.checkListFile(sh.getShipmentHeader().getBillToCustomer());

            if (!readLine.isEmpty())
            {
                int orderCount = 0;
                int index = readLine.indexOf(";") + 1;

                String customerName = readLine.substring(index, readLine.indexOf(";", index)).trim();

                index = readLine.indexOf(";", index) + 1;
                String to = readLine.substring(index, readLine.length()).trim();



                if (!billMap.containsKey(sh.getShipmentHeader().getBillToCustomer()))
                    {
                    billMap.put(sh.getShipmentHeader().getBillToCustomer(), 1);
                    orderCount = 1;
                    }
                else
                    {
                    billMap.put(sh.getShipmentHeader().getBillToCustomer(), ((int) billMap.get(sh.getShipmentHeader().getBillToCustomer())) + 1);
                    orderCount = (int) billMap.get(sh.getShipmentHeader().getBillToCustomer());
                    } 

                outboundMessage += sh.getShipmentHeader().getOrderNumber() + li ;

                logger.info("On-Demand Outbound Export Info: " + orderCount + " processed out of " + sh.getShipmentHeader().getOrderCount() + 
                        " for " + customerName);


                if (orderCount == sh.getShipmentHeader().getOrderCount())
                    {
                    Email email = new Email();
                    billMap.remove(sh.getShipmentHeader().getBillToCustomer());
                    outboundMessage += li + "Total of #"+ sh.getShipmentHeader().getOrderCount() + " orders processed for "+ customerName + li ;
                    logger.info("On-Demand Email sent for " + customerName);
                    System.out.println(outboundMessage);
                    email.outboundEmail("TEST: Orders for " + customerName + " complete", outboundMessage, to);
                    outboundMessage = "";
                    email = null;
                    }}
```

I been working on this for days, where am I going wrong.

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. Could you try reading through it and either rewriting it or making it clearer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are having difficulty obtaining information from xmls. I suggest using XStream [1]. It is capable of serialising objects to xml and back. By using XStream, you can get an Object from the xml and compare variables (Lnumber and Ocount) easily.

If you insist using this code, I suggest adding comments to notify us what you are doing, but if want an easier alternative to work with xml files using java, I highly suggest using XStream as a solution.

[1]  http://x-stream.github.io/

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't explain the my problem properly, I have created a object to parse that information and have getters and setters for Lnumber and OCount in place. However is it possible to make a array or Map so that I can store all the xml objects and then retrieve the data that i need when grouping duplicates?

Comment: Lnumber and OCount are stored in a xml file, and you are trying to obtain them so that you can compare with other xml files right?

Comment: If that is the case, go through the easy 2-minute tutorial which is on the site I referenced. That will get you started to obtain objects from xml files and making the grouping of duplicates a much easier task...